# Show that if a symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ satisfies $A = A^{2}$, then all its eigenvalues must be either 1 or 0.

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, symmetric-matrices

Show that if a symmetric matrix $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times  n}$ satisfies $A = A^{2}$, then all its eigenvalues must be either 1 or 0.

I think I'm able to show that the eigenvalue is equal to 1 through the following:

$$ Av - \lambda v = 0$$
$$ v(A - \lambda I) = 0 $$
$$ A-\lambda I = 0 $$
$$ A = \lambda I $$
$$ AA = \lambda I A$$
$$ A^{2} = \lambda A$$
$$ A = \lambda A $$
$$ \lambda = 1 $$

How can I show that the eigenvalue can also be equal to 0?

Comment: Hint: if a matrix satisfies this, what are its possible minimal polynomials? Note that the characteristic polynomial and the minimal polynomial have the same zero set.

Comment: Also, there are some incorrect steps in your calculation. First, just because $(A - \lambda I)v = 0$ we cannot conclude that $A - \lambda I = 0 $. In fact, there are matrices $A$ satisfying $A^2 = A$ which are not a scalar multiple of the identity.

Comment: $\lambda(\lambda -1) = 0$ has only two solutions.

Comment: "Av−λv=0
 
v(A−λI)=0" Multiplication is not communitive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $\lambda$ be an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$ and $\mathbf{x}$ an eigenvector corresponding to the eigenvalue  $\lambda$

We have

$$A\mathbf{x}=\lambda \mathbf{x}$$,$\mathbf{x}\neq0$.

Then we have $$A^2\mathbf{x}=A\mathbf{x}\stackrel{(*)}{=} \lambda \mathbf{x}$$.

Also we have \begin{align*} 
A^2\mathbf{x}=A(A\mathbf{x})\stackrel{(*)}{=}A(\lambda \mathbf{x})=\lambda (A\mathbf{x})\stackrel{(*)}{=}\lambda (\lambda \mathbf{x})=\lambda^2\mathbf{x}. 
\end{align*}
Comparing these last $2$ we get $\lambda \mathbf{x}=\lambda^2 \mathbf{x}$.

By solving the last equation and since $\lambda$ is our eigenvalue we get that $\lambda=0$ or $\lambda=1$